# Google Geochart border colour

Tags: google-visualization

Is there any way to customise region border colours in Google Geocharts? The API mentions background stroking but not region stroking.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't do it with the API settings, but you can do it with CSS.

```
#map_canvas path {
stroke-width:1; /* control the countries borders width */
stroke:#6699cc; /* choose a color for the border */
}
```

You can see it in action on my website, here: 
http://cmoreira.net/interactive-world-maps-demo/advanced-customization/
I'm trying to document more CSS tweaks there also.

Hope it helps! Cheers